# geom_smooth() with facet_grid() versus mgcv:::gam with by=""

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I am comparing the output from a gam performed through ggplot2's geom_smooth using facet_grid versus a gam using the mgcv:::gam with specified "by" factor visualized through visreg. Herewith data and code:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
dat <- iris %>% mutate(response = sample(rep(c(0,1),length.out=150/2),150, replace=T))

#Just the output from geom_smooth
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(Sepal.Length,response)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y~s(x, bs="cs"), method.args=list("binomial")) +
  facet_grid(.~Species)
#Now performing the gam through mgcv:::gam specifying by=Species
library(mgcv)
gam <- gam(dat, formula = response~s(Sepal.Length, bs="cs", by=Species),family = binomial())
#Comparing the two different outputs
library(visreg)
visreg(gam, "Sepal.Length", by="Species", scale="response", gg=T)  +
  guides(color=F)+
  geom_smooth(data=dat,aes(Sepal.Length,response),
              method="gam", formula = y~s(x, bs="cs"), method.args=list("binomial"), color="red", fill="green")
```

[image: geom_smooth output shown with red smooth and green CI, mgcv with blue smooth and grey CI]

Basically, what I think happens is that the mgcv:::gam bases its gam smooths on some type of "imputed" data for areas where there is actually none for each Species level. It seems the setting in geom_smooth() avoids this. Does anyone know how to counteract this, so that the output from geom_smooth and mgcv:::gam is identical?

EDIT:

Based on the answer from user20650, the code was updated to:

```
library(mgcv)
gam <- gam(dat, formula = response~Species + s(Sepal.Length, bs="cs", by=Species),family = binomial()) 
library(visreg)
visreg(gam, "Sepal.Length", by="Species", scale="response", gg=T)  +
  guides(color=F)+
  geom_smooth(data=dat,aes(Sepal.Length,response),
              method="gam", formula = y~s(x, bs="cs"), method.args=list("binomial"), color="red", fill="green",
              fullrange=T)
```

[image: updated plot]

As can be seen in the above plot there are subtle differences (mostly in the CI) in the two methods. This is accentuated should we look at e.g. set.seed(100):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
dat <- iris %>% mutate(response = sample(rep(c(0,1),length.out=150/2),150, replace=T))

library(mgcv)
gam <- gam(dat, formula = response~Species + s(Sepal.Length, bs="cs", by=Species),family = binomial()) 
library(visreg)
visreg(gam, "Sepal.Length", by="Species", scale="response", gg=T)  +
  guides(color=F)+
  geom_smooth(data=dat,aes(Sepal.Length,response),
              method="gam", formula = y~s(x, bs="cs"), method.args=list("binomial"), color="red", fill="green",
              fullrange=T)
```

[image: new seed plot]

Can anyone explain the differences in the two methods, and how to generate identical output from geom_smooth() in mgcv:::gam and vice versa (both in the case of fullrange=T as well as fullrange=F)?

Comment: Try `formula = response ~ Species + s(...`  ; I think the `by` variable should generally be added to the model, and probably `fullrange=TRUE`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you have any suggestions on how to get the mgcv gam to not consider fullrange=T and only consider the observed data in each Species level?

Comment: I suppose you could pass the data you want to model to predict.

Comment: I think ggplot splits the data by the facet variable and then fits three different models. mgcv fit one model with an interaction term. Id generally recommend doing the modelling outside of the plot method.